# Does the COPY CSV command in Redshift load in the order defined in the headers?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have some code which pulls CSV's from S3 into a Redshift table. I'm getting issues whereby, if the CSV is stored in a certain column order, the copy command doesn't match the column order in the CSV header.

So if I have a CSV with the columns `id|age|name` and I have a Redshift table with the columns `id|name|age`, it will attempt to pull in the data in the CSV header order. So in this case, it will attempt to pull the name CSV column into the age column in Redshift, which causes a type error.

My query is:

```
copy schema.#tmp from <s3file> 
iam_role <iamrole> 
acceptinvchars 
truncatecolumns
IGNOREBLANKLINES
ignoreheader 1
                  COMPUPDATE OFF
                  STATUPDATE OFF
                  delimiter ','
                  timeformat 'auto'
                  dateformat 'auto';
```

Do I need to define the column order in the copy command to match the two up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COPY` ignores column names in the file; the columns are matched from left to right.

But you can specify a column list in the `COPY` statement. Use that to tell PostgreSQL the order of the columns in the file.